# Evaluating a Complex Triple Integral with an Infinite Sum

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, special-functions

I recently came across an interesting integral and attempted to solve it, but encountered some difficulties. The integral is as follows:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz)/k}}{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} e^{-(s+n)^2}ds}{(1+s)^2} ds} dxdydz$$

Here's how I approached it: I first recognized the numerator involves an infinite sum with alternating signs and fractional terms, and the denominator involves another infinite sum with exponential and polynomial terms. Let's denote the numerator as N and the denominator as D. I tried to investigate the convergence of these sums and determine if they converge to finite values for all values of the variables involved. However, I realized that the convergence of these sums is highly dependent on the specific values of the variables and the behavior of the integrands, which can be quite challenging to analyze. Mathematically, I encountered difficulties in evaluating N and D for all values of x, y, z and s Both the numerator N and denominator D integrands are highly complex. Let's denote the integrand of N as f(x,y,z,k) and the integrand of D as g(s,n). These integrands involve multiple exponential terms, polynomial expressions, and infinite sums. I attempted to simplify or manipulate these expressions to facilitate integration, but quickly realized that it is not straightforward and may require advanced techniques such as special functions, complex analysis, or advanced integration methods. Mathematically, I encountered difficulties in finding closed-form expressions for f(x, y, z, k) and g(s, n) that can be easily integrated. Upon further investigation, I realized that this integral may not have a known closed-form solution. While some integrals can be evaluated using standard techniques, this particular integral seems to be highly complicated and lacks a known closed-form solution. Mathematically, I encountered difficulties in finding a closed-form expression for the given integral, which can be a common challenge in advanced mathematics.
Please help me I really don’t know what to do regards, Dylan.

Comment: Welcome. This post would be more well-received if you mentioned why thisintegral interests you: I just look at something like that and run... has it occurred in an engineering application?

Comment: Note that since $n$ is being summed over and $s$ is integrated over, the integral in the denominator is just some number. Therefore it can be pulled out of the integral.

Comment: @FShrike It has

Comment: I guessed so. Well, it could benefit you to give a little of that context in your post

Comment: This integral is either divergent or zero. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2yz + 2xz = (x + y + z)^2$, so the integrand is purely a function of $x+y+z$. Rotate to some coordinate system where $x' = x + y + z$ and the integral is now of the form $\int_{\mathbb R^3} f(x')dx'dy'dz'$, which obviously diverges unless $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x')dx' = 0$

Comment: I am going to remove "contest-math" tag since it is not apparent at all why this problem is related to contest-math. A math problem is deemed good for contests usually when there is a known solution that is unexpected and elegant to some extent.